# How to solve IllegalMonitorStateException while calling a method with out breaking the loops present on it

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, iterator

i have two classes one is Manager and another one is parser. Parser class contain a method called **getRecord()**, which call a another method called **getNextRecord()**.

There are two iterations in **getNextRecord()** method i.e. parent Iteration and child Iteration, hear parent Iteration iterate for 100 times and on every parent Iteration child iterate for 10 times by printing a number of child iteration.

now what i need is when i call a **getRecord()** method from Manager class 
only one child iteration should happen by printing a iteration message  meaning parent Iteration will start and child iterate for one time and print SYSO statement there after loop should pause and main thread will go for waiting state without braking iteration / loop.

Again when ever i call **getRecord()** method it should print one child iteration and wait until i call **getRecord()** method next time with out breaking a loop

**What i required is when ever i call getRecord() method it should print only one message with out breaking while loops present in Parser class.**

while implementing this i am getting exception **IllegalMonitorStateException**  hoq can i solve this

Manager class

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class Manager {

    public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          Properties properties = new Properties();

          Parser parser = new Parser(properties);

          parser.getRecord();
          parser.getRecord();
          parser.getRecord();
          parser.getRecord();

          /*Thread tProducer = new Thread(new Parser(properties));
          tProducer.start();*/
       }
}
```

Parser class

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class Parser extends Thread
{
       private Properties properties;

       Parser parser = null;

       private int parentIteration = 0;

       public Parser(Properties properties)
       {
          this.properties = properties;
          parser = new Parser();
       }

       public Parser(){

       }

       public void getNextRecord()
       {
          while (parentIteration <= 100) {

             try {

                 int childIteration = 0;

                 while (childIteration <= 10) {

                    System.out.println("Record "+ ++childIteration);
                    parser.wait();
                 }

             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
             }

             ++parentIteration;
          }
       }

       void getRecord()
       {
           getNextRecord();
           parser.notify();
       }
    }
```

any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Stack trace

```
Record 1Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at Parser.getNextRecord(Parser.java:32)
    at Parser.getRecord(Parser.java:46)
    at Manager.main(Manager.java:11)
```

Comment: You cannot call `wait()` without having a lock on the object in question.

Comment: if possible post your full stack trace

Comment: `synchronized(this){parse.wait()}` call `wait()` method in `synchronized` block, to call `wait()` thread should acquire a lock of that object

Comment: @subburoyal  thanks for the replay i don't no much on threads, how can i implement lock on the object

Comment: `synchronized(this){parse.wait()}` like this

Comment: @subburoyal you mean instead of getNextRecord() method i should override run() method and in synchronized block i should call run() method

Comment: @subburoya but still i am getting same exception